# Unexpected result: Why does accessing an undefined variable not throw an error?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {
    name: 'zhangsan',
    getName: function() {
        alert(name)
    }
};
a.getName();
```

Why does it alert `""` instead of throwing an error without `this` in front of `name`?

Comment: Because there is no variable called `name` in the scope of the function.  Try `alert(this.name)`

Comment: In this case,it should return an error,but it returns ''.

Comment: `name` refers to `window.name`, so no error is thrown. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name

Comment: @FelixKling: I forgot about `window.name`.  That would explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a property on the window object called name which default value is "" http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp

Answer (score 2):

Because in this line:

```
alert(name);
```

...`name` is a simple variable reference. In this case, it resolves to the global variable `name` (the name of the window, since global variables are properties of the global object, and the global object on browsers is the window).

To use the `name` property of your object, you have to do that explicitly:

```
alert(this.name);
```

Answer (score 1):

`name` is not defined (by you) in both the scope of your function and it's parent (`window`). To refer to the object itself, you have to use `this`:

```
var a = {
    name: 'zhangsan',
    getName: function() {
        alert(this.name);
    }
};
a.getName();
```

PS: Apparently [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name) does exist, and `name` in your code is referring to it, thus not throwing an error but returning an incorrect value.

Comment: Actually, `window.name` exists ;) Otherwise the code would throw a reference error.

Comment: @FelixKling - Totally forgot about that!

Answer (score 0):

It's realy easy to understand :

```
var name = "asdasdasd";
var a = {name: 'zhangsan', getName: function() {
    alert("A name : " + name);
    alert("A this.name : " + this.name);
}};
var b = {name: 'BBBBasfdasdasd', getName: function() {
    alert("B name : " + name);
    alert("B this.name : " + this.name);
}};

a.getName();
b.getName();
```

You can try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/jvEq2/1/

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the question. He's wondering why no error was thrown for accessing what appeared to be an undeclared variable. Normally that would result in a ReferenceError,.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, you are not using `this` which refers to the object itself.

Do this:

```
var a = {name: 'zhangsan', getName: function() {
alert(this.name)}
};
a.getName();
```

Also I think you already have a global variable name whose value is `""` otherwise you should have got `ReferenceError`

Comment: yeah, updated. Not in my right mind after reaching the 200 cap limit :)